# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object using PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried everything and I keep getting an error. When I look at the URL it shows an integer and it should show the post title. I think the problem is there, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

This is my controller and view code:

```
    public function getSingle($slug) {
        $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
        return view('oilnotes.single')->withPost($post);

    }


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello,

are you sure that `$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();` actually returns an object and that your slug is valid ?

Can you place `dd($post, $slug);` after that line and show us the result ?

Comment: You've said that the url shows an integer but you're looking for a slug, do you have a post with a slug (not id) that matches that integer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that `$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();` is not empty, you can see what's inside by using `dd($post);`. I would also suggest using `->FirstOrFail();` instead of `->first();`.
`->first();` returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exists, it returns `null`.
`->FirstOrFail();` returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exists, it throws a 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

You may use the null coalescing operator `??` ( introduced in PHP 7). It's used to check if the value is set or null, or in other words, if the value exists and not null, then it returns the first operand, otherwise, it returns the second operand.

```
<h1>{{ $post->title ?? 'DEFAULT' }}</h1>
<p>{{ $post->body ?? 'DEFAULT' }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use firstOrFail(). It will redirect to 404 if no record found for slug.

```
public function getSingle($slug) {
    $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('oilnotes.single')->withPost($post);

}
```